# PHP int casting how to format?

Tags: php, math, int

```
(int)$ref_ios_24_sign/(int)$ref_ios_24 * 100 

Result : 35.7894736842
Wanted : 35.7
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two simple options:

```
round(35.7894736842, 1);
sprintf('%0.1f', 35.7894736842);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = (int)$ref_ios_24_sign/(int)$ref_ios_24 * 100;
$a = (float)$a;
number_format ( $a , 1)
```

[PHP: number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)